# Transparent shapes in Matlab to TeX when using Matlab Fill

Tags: graphics, matlab

I want to export figures with transparent shapes in Matlab to TeX. For the following code, the triangle will appear transparent in Matlab but will be solid blue when I generate the tex file using `\input{triangle.pgf}`

Matlab Code:

```
x = [ 1         -0.5         -0.5            1];
y = [0      0.86603     -0.86603 -2.4493e-016];

f = figure;
t = fill(x,y,'b'); 
alpha(t,0.05);

matfig2pgf('fignr',1,'filename','triangle.pgf','figwidth',14);
```

Comment: Can you show us the resulting source-code 'triangle.pgf'. I assume there is just a single parameter missing for transperency called 'opacity=x'.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the old `matfig2pgf`, try [`matlab2tikz`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz). It's newer, more supported, and uses pgfplots.  Replace your call to `matfig2pfg` with `matlab2tikz('triagle.tikz')`, and then use it in your LaTeX document like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}

\begin{document}
  \input{triangle.tikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `matlab2tikz` doesn't work when using `geoshow` from the mapping toolbox in Matlab however.

Comment: Ah, I don't have the mapping toolbox, so I'm afraid I cannot help you there. I presume simply exporting to PDF or EPS isn't satisfactory?

Comment: that would be correct